# Cordova Ajax call throwing net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova

I have two Ajax calls but one of the Ajax calls are returning net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

The Ajax call urls are coming from WordPress Woocommerce RestApi.

When I run chrome in mode - `chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security` - the error disappears and everything is working correctly.

**Error**

[image]

- Ajax call that is **not working**:

  ```
  $.ajax({
      url: "https://krii.000webhostapp.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products/categories?per_page=99",
      success: function(json){
          console.log("Success", json);
           $.each(json, function (index, categories) {
               //console.log(categories);
               catego.push({Cat_Name: categories.name});
              //console.log(catego);
              $('select#categories2').append('<option data-id="> categories.id">'+categories.name+'</option>');
          });
      },
      error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
          console.log(textStatus,errorThrown)
      },
      beforeSend: function (xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('ck_...:cs_...'));
      },
      type: 'GET',
      contentType: 'json'
  });
  ```
- Ajax call that **is working**:

  ```
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://..../wp-json/wc/v2/products/categories?per_page=99",
      success: function(json){
          console.log("Success", json);
           $.each(json, function (index, categories) {
               //console.log(categories);
               catego.push({Cat_Name: categories.name});
              //console.log(catego);
              $('select#categories').append('<option data-id="> categories.id">'+categories.name+'</option>');
          });
      },
      error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
          console.log(textStatus,errorThrown)
      },
      beforeSend: function (xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('ck_...:cs_...'));
      },
      type: 'GET',
      contentType: 'json'     
  });
  ```

How exactly I can fix this, cause it does not work on mobile device.

Comment: Can you post the error as text rather than an image?

Answer (score 0):

This error ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR is found in Google chrome. With latest updates of google chrome it is depracted. This protocol was added for faster web load and security. You can learn more from [how-to-fix-err_spdy_protocol_error-in-google-chrome-2019](https://icodemate.com/how-to-fix-err_spdy_protocol_error-in-google-chrome-2019/)